# Querying Fusion Tables and filtering by date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I'm sending a Query through the Fusion Tables V2 API using a WHERE statement to filter by date, but I can't manage to find the correct date format (the ones provided in the documentation are useless).

```
    var query = "SELECT 'amount', 'closedate' FROM ************ " + 
                "WHERE 'closedate' >= '01/01/2018' ";

    var access_token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
    var dataSourceUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=' + encodeURIComponent(query) +
                        '&typed=true'+
                        '&access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(access_token);

    var jqxhr = $.get(dataSourceUrl, handleResponse, "json");
```

I always get an empty response like this:

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "amount",
  "closedate"
 ]
}
```

How can I set the date format to do a correct filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#returns):

> **Filtering on DATETIME**
>
> When filtering on a column of type DATETIME, the value should be 
>   formatted as one of the following supported formats:
>
> - MMM dd, yy
> - MM/dd/yy
> - MM-dd-yy
> - MMM-dd-yy
> - yyyy.MM.dd
> - dd-MMM-yy
> - MMM/yy
> - MMM yy
> - dd/MMM/yy
> - yyyy

It looks like MM/DD/YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY are not supported formats. However, the closest to your format is yyyy.MM.dd. You can write code to convert between formats as necessary. A simple regex should do the trick.